# What type is the break instruction on MARS (MIPS Assembly)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm writing an article about the evolution of programming languages and wrote a small program in MIPS Assembly that calculates the first 100 prime numbers. On of the (pseudo)instructions of this program is 'rem $t3, $t0, $t2' which is converted to the following four native instructions:

```
bne $10, $0, 0x00000001
break
div $8, $10
mfhi$11
```

I've never noticed that break instruction before, so I've searched all over the place and could barely find any mention of the break instruction or it's type.

The only two documents I could find where [this one](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~franklin/64/lectures/mipsassemblytutorial.pdf) that states 'break' as an instruction used by the debugger and [this other one](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15740-f97/public/doc/mips-isa.pdf) that states 'break' as an instruction with three parts: special (6 bits), code (20 bits) and break (6 bits) but it makes no reference to what type this instruction is. It certainly isn't of type R, I or J.

So I was wondering:

1. Is the break instruction part of the MIPS ISA or an instruction only
   MARS recognises?
2. What is the instruction type of the break instruction?
3. How does it transfer the control to an exception handler, in hardware?
4. Does it change the Program Counter (PC) register?

Comment: What's the numeric value of the machine code word?  I forget if MARS shows that to you easily, but if not you could just put a label on it and `lw` the word of code.

Comment: The opcode is 0x00. Yeah MARS shows the hex values for each instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume I: Introduction to the MIPS32™ Architecture*, only the R-Type format has a `function` field. `BREAK` has a `function` field, thus it is an R-Type instruction.

Since the `BREAK` instruction takes no operands, it doesn't make use of bits 6..25 for that purpose. This isn't all that unusual; for example, `SLL` doesn't make use of the `rs` field so those bits are set to zero, and `MULT` doesn't make use of either the `rd` or `sa` fields so all those bits are set to zero.

As for what happens: the relevant bits in CP0 register 13 (`Cause`) would be set to indicate that an exception occurred as the result of hitting a breakpoint. Control would then be transferred to the exception handler code at some fixed address.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I haven't had the chance to study coprocessors much, so I guess now it's a good opportunity. I downloaded Volumes I, II and III of the MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers. If you happen to have any more resources on this, please share :) Thank you!